# How to select top 300 for each orders total order item value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to view the top 300 items ordered by total net price, how do I do this please?

Using SSMS 2014

If I remove group by I get error: Column 'orderitems.orderid' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Please see workings below:

```
select top 300

orderitems.orderid, orders.traderid, orders.orderdate, 
SUM(orderitems.nettprice) AS nettprice

from orderitems

INNER JOIN orders ON orders.tradertype = 'S' AND orders.id = 
orderitems.orderid 

where orderitems.ordertype = 'PO'

group by orderitems.orderid, orders.traderid, orders.orderdate, 
orderitems.nettprice

order by orderitems.nettprice  DESC
```

Comment: What does "best" mean here? Why are you using a `GROUP BY` when the only column you aggregate is in a subquery, *and* it's in the `GROUP BY` as well. The above doesn't make sense. What are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: Without `ORDER BY` it'll just be 300 'random' elements that are returned.

Comment: I want to view the top 300 items ordered by total net price

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: I was editing jarlh

Comment: You've included `orderitems.netprice` in your `GROUP BY` clause. You'll get a separate row for each distinct `netprice` value. I suspect that's not what you want.

Comment: Hi Richard, yes that's right, I am getting a distinct net price totaling the purchase order items for each purchase order, I'd like to get the top 300 items by total order value

Comment: What defines the "total net price" then?

Comment: @Larnu Can you please explain what you mean? If the sum is of orderitems.nettprice this totals each purchase order

Comment: And what defines that? What defines s
 Single purchase?

Comment: @Larnu for each line there is a purchase order item number 'itemnumber', the item 'partid' and quantity  'traderquantity'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to order by the `SUM` value. You can either put that in the `ORDER BY` explicitly, or you can use the `SELECT` column name *without* a table reference (in other words the column alias you use in the `SELECT`)

> I strongly recommend you use short table aliases to make your code more readable

```sql
select top 300
  oi.orderid,
  o.traderid,
  o.orderdate, 
  SUM(oi.nettprice) AS nettprice
from orderitems AS oi
INNER JOIN orders AS o ON o.tradertype = 'S' AND o.id = oi.orderid 
where oi.ordertype = 'PO'
group by
  oi.orderid, o.traderid, o.orderdate
order by
  nettprice DESC
-- alternatively
order by
  SUM(oi.nettprice) DESC
```

Comment: This does tally up correctly, thank you :) I will be able to use this for sales & purchase analysis in the future. I'll also use short table aliases for any posts in the future. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you need here is a windowed `SUM` and then a `TOP`. The `PARTITION BY` clause is based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70018592/how-to-select-top-300-for-each-orders-total-order-item-value?noredirect=1#comment123777219_70018592):

```sql
SELECT TOP (300)
       oi.orderid,
       o.traderid,
       o.orderdate,
       SUM(oi.nettprice) OVER (PARTITION BY oi.itemnumber, oi.partid, oi.quantity) AS totalnettprice
FROM dbo.orderitems oi
     INNER JOIN dbo.orders o ON o.id = oi.orderid
WHERE o.tradertype = 'S'
  AND oi.ordertype = 'PO'
ORDER BY oi.totalnettprice DESC;
```

Comment: @Lamu thank you but this doesn't tally up correctly, perhaps it's a detail I've missed  through my own  table references

Comment: There is no `m` in my alias, @StuartOxley .

Comment: I see now, I simply misread

Answer (score 0):

Very simple:

```
select top 300
    itm.orderid, 
    ord.traderid, 
    ord.orderdate, 
    SUM(itm.nettprice) AS price
from orderitems itm
INNER JOIN orders ord ON 
            ord.tradertype = 'S' AND ord.id = itm.orderid 
where itm.ordertype = 'PO'
group by 
    itm.orderid, 
    ord.traderid, 
    ord.orderdate
order by price DESC
```